# how to find the point out of the contours using opencv-python

Tags: image-processing, opencv, python

I have the contour coordinates obtained by the cv2.findContours. But I want to get the points outer of the contours one pixel , how can I do that?

Comment: Your question is not clean to me. Please give more details or provide an image or diagram. Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the information guides in the **help center** (https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular, "How to Ask A Good Question" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and "How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Well, you can try these two approaches and see which one gives you the desired results. First, draw 1 pixel-wide contour on top of your contour and then do the find contour on that resulting image. Resulting image should be displaced by 1 px outward. 

Second, you can try to dilate image by say 2x2 kernel and then get contours. This one would not be as precise, but you can experiment with the kernel shapes (for e.g. 3x3 elliptical etc.) and see any of those give you desired results.

Comment: If I understand, draw your contour white filled on a black background. Then use morphology dilate to expand the region. Then get the contour of the expanded region.